# excel gathering information into buckets

Tags: excel

I have a pretty simple question that I'm struggling with.

I have a column with Growth rates changing from 0-60% i.e/ 5% 10% 23% 37% ...etc.

What I want to do is take this column, and assign a certain range into a bucket. So if a growth rates falls between 0-5% it will be assigned a 0-5% cateogry. Eqaully, the number 23% would fall under 20-25% growth rate.

I'm just looking for a way to "subdivide the range" sort of speak.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking something like this?

[image]

Bucket A

```
=IF(A3<25, A3, "")
```

Bucket B

=IF(AND(A3>25, A3<50), A3, "")

Bucket C

```
=IF(AND(A3>50, A3<75), A3, "")
```

Bucket D

```
=IF(A3>75, A3, "")
```

Comment: Well its more along the lines off for a whole range. So If (A1:A50<5%, Bucket 1, otherwise bucket 2, 3, 4 depending on the bucket's corresponding rate.

Comment: So you'd like the arithmetic average of all values in A1:A50 assigned to the appropriate bucket?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single helper column with variable bucket names then you can use a formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,A1<=0.25),"0-25%",
     IF(AND(A1>0.25,A1<=0.5),"25-50%",
         IF(AND(A1>0.5,A1<=0.75),"50-75%",
             IF(AND(A1>0.75,A1<=1),"75-100%","Out of Range"
             )
         )
     )
 )
```

It's ok for a small number of buckets, but nesting several IFs can get unwieldy if you have too many categories.

Alternatively, you can use `MROUND` which rounds any value to the nearest multiple of n. With a little bit of concatenation you can define as many n-wide buckets as needed like so:

```
=IF(MROUND(A1,0.05)>A1,100*(MROUND(A1,0.05)-0.05)&"-"&100*MROUND(A1,0.05)&"%",
                       100*MROUND(A1,0.05)&"-"&100*(MROUND(A1,0.05)+0.05)&"%")
```